# How to convert duration strings to seconds?

Tags: pandas, datetime, time, strptime

I have such a column in a pandas dataframe:

```
duration
1 day 22:12:15.778543
2 days 10:09:07.118723
00:18:23.985112
```

I would like to convert this `duration` to seconds.

How can I do this? I am not sure if this is possible because of the special string format I got (`1 day`, `2 days` etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
df['s'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']).dt.total_seconds()
print (df)
                 duration              s
0   1 day 22:12:15.778543  166335.778543
1  2 days 10:09:07.118723  209347.118723
2         00:18:23.985112    1103.985112
```

Comment: Alternative `df['seconds'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['duration']).total_seconds()`

Comment: @Corralien - yes, possible solution. But I prefer solution for `Series`, not `Index`

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael! Did not think it is that easy.